# nodejs and react diferent ports for socket.io?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I have my project in react launched on port 3000 and a nodejs server on port 8080

How do I connect the server sockets with the client if they are on different ports?

Comment: If your React project is launched via Create-React-App, use the built-in proxy. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Answer (score 1):

I did [something recently](https://github.com/praveenscience/DoodleWithNodeSocket/blob/master/app.js), so I am gonna suggest the same. You can use something like this:

```js
const express = require("express");
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);
const port = 3100;

app.use('/', createProxyMiddleware({
   target: "http://localhost:3000",
   changeOrigin: true
}));

const onConnection = socket => {
  socket.on("channel", data => socket.broadcast.emit("channel", data));
};

io.on("connection", onConnection);

http.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server started in port " + port + ".");
});
```

If you're just trying to run a normal Node JS + React JS Server for `CORS` bypass, you can use `proxy` option in `package.json`:

```
"proxy": "http://my-api-server:port",
```

For more details you can read [Using React's Proxy to get ahead of CORS & use HTTPS for API calls](https://blog.praveen.science/using-reacts-proxy-to-get-ahead-of-cors/).

Comment: thanks! I was able to achieve it, now the react app starts from localhost: 8080!